# What is the best way to Download Images and texts and use them in my app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I created an app which load data from server and format it in specific format in android UI components, like text view and image view, but the loading take long time, i want to know what is the best way to decrease the load time and increase the loading speed and the quality of my app, if you know a book name or blog or wiki don't hesitate to till me.
If you want to see the developed and published app which I'm talking about, please visit [Wasfati](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alameenTech.android) app on android market.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you used Lazy loading of images? if not use it

Comment: I'm using native android SDK, not html or jQuery

Comment: Yes i am talking about native android only

Answer (score 2):

To load the data from server it is better to use `Asynctask` along with ProgressDialog. And to load images Lazy loading of images  is the best solution.

[Read here for AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

[fedors lazylist sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/792232)

Comment: I waana check it and poat my comment here

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Always keep the `UI` work on UI thread, and `Non-UI` work on the Non-UI thread, was a good programming approach, but became a law with the arrival of `HoneyComb` android Version.

**2.** When an Android App **start** you begin on `UI` thread, now to keep UI thread responsive, we need to do **all the process heavy task** on the `Non-UI thread`.

**3** You can do this using a `simple thread` along with `Handler`, where you do the Non-UI work in the thread and then show the Output on the UI using the Handler.

**4.** The other better approach is `AsyncTask`, which was introduced in android, and is also known as **Painless Threading**. This automatically `Synchronizes` the UI and Non-UI thread.

**5.** Now about the Delay, this sometimes depends on your **Internet connectivity**... But yes using the thread to handle different Non-UI work and then putting it on the UI thread, helps in reducing the lags...

Comment: Can you mention by link to blog or example on web? #Kumar Vivek

Comment: See this......http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html  and this....  http://android-apps-blog.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-use-asynctask-to-load-images-on.html